# Visual Studio not finding all source during debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have two C++ solutions in Visual Studio.

My 1st solution is used to generate a lib file. The Project Settings are C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format = "C7 Compatible (/Z7)". Everything builds correctly and is debuggable from my 1st solution (I have a second project with a main which allows for testing).

For my second solution in project properties C/C++ -> General I list the Additional Include Directories. I specify the additional library directories for the linker. And I specify the lib file in Additional Dependencies. My solution builds and runs correctly. However, when trying to step through code in the debugger from solution 1 some cpp files are automatically found. However, other files will show the "Find Source" dialog box. Is there a way to get VS to automatically find all source files from the lib generated by project 1?

Comment: You could try adding the include paths under project properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories, e.g. add `$(SolutionDir)\YourLibraryProject\include;`. I've encountered tools like resharper not finding include paths specified under C++ > Additional Include Directories (though never VS' debugger itself...)

Answer (score 0):

I have only had a problem with this when the code is in a dll and their companion pdb files are not in the same folder. This typically happens when you copy the dlls at runtime but do not copy the pdbs.